# What's the difference using Lizard or OCLint to populate SonarQube Objective-C Complexity measures?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sonarqube, code-metrics

Using SonarQube 6.2 with [Backelite Objective-C scanner](https://github.com/Backelite/sonar-objective-c) plugin for an iOS project. The Complexity page under the Measures section only displays if I have the scanner script generate and upload the [Lizard](https://github.com/terryyin/lizard) complexity report. It will not appear simply by running [OCLint](https://github.com/oclint/oclint) and uploading that report. Note that both the OCLint **and** Lizard steps are normal for the Backelite Obj-C plugin.
[image: SonarQube]
I don't understand the difference between what OCLint generates for Cyclomatic Complexity vs what Lizard generates. They both seem to focus on code complexity, but the OCLint complexity only shows up as an "Issue" in SonarQube.
[image: Typical OCLint Issue]
Am I misunderstanding code complexity in the context of SonarQube?